# Undefined variable: params

Tags: php

Ok so, I'm creating a website, and on the website I have a little "create a user" account type, I've put that on index.php and its assigned all its values and stuff so Admins can create accounts when they log in...

Anyways, So, I'm receiving this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: params in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\staff_inc\core.inc.php on line 62
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: params in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\staff_inc\core.inc.php on line 63
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: params in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\staff_inc\core.inc.php on line 62
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: params in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\staff_inc\core.inc.php on line 63

And on that file, line 62 and 63 I have

```
$salt1  = md5( $params['core']['salt1'] );
$salt2  = md5( $params['core']['salt2'] );
```

And I'm not sure on how to fix it?
My full code for that function is

```
public function encrypt( $string ) {        
    global $vars;
    //let's md5 that salt and the string.
    $salt1  = md5( $params['core']['salt1'] );
    $salt2  = md5( $params['core']['salt2'] );
    $string = md5( $string );
    //stick them together.
    $string = $salt1 . $salt1 . $salt2 . $string . $salt2 . $salt1;
    //sha1 then md5 them again.
    $string = sha1( $string );
    $string = md5( $string );
    return $string; 
}
```

Comment: u have not defined $params

Comment: is it $vars = $params or $params it self global?

Comment: u didnt respond yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice is very clear: you didn't defined `$params` in your function.

**Solution 1:**

If you are passing `$params` as a parameter of your function than you need to add in parameters as:

```
public function encrypt( $string, $params ) {
....
```

**Solution 2:**

If `$params` is a global variable than you need to defined as:

```
public function encrypt( $string ) {
    global $vars, $params; // defined here
    // your remaining stuff    
}
```

**Solution 3:**

As i ask in comments, if `$params` is equal to `$vars`, because you are not using `$vars` in your function than you can use like:

```
public function encrypt( $string ) {
    global $vars;

    $salt1  = md5( $vars['core']['salt1'] );
    $salt2  = md5( $vars['core']['salt2'] );
    $string = md5( $string );

    // your remaining stuff    
}
```

**Side Note:**

I don't think, is there any fourth option.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `$params` should be global variable:

```
public function encrypt( $string ) {

     global $vars; /* you don't use this, btw. */

     global $params;

     /* other code goes here */

}
```